# PHP CLi - Set running on cmd line then continue? Don't want bash script to wait

Tags: command-line, sh, php

Hopefully a quick question. I have a .sh script running a php script - the php takes some time to complete and I want the .sh script to proceed.

Is that possible? And if so, how so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `php somescript.php &` ? The `&` at the end causes the sh script to continue executing.

If you want the php script to outlive the shell script, try this:

```
nohup php somescript.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Does the & do something there? Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: Yes, it causes the sh script to not wait for the php script to finish before continuing its execution

Comment: Sounds spot on, let me just see

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something: I'm doing: php -f /home/script.php $2 &

Comment: If you do `php -f somescript.php &`
`echo "next command"`,
you should see "next command" printed before the php script is terminated.

Comment: To put a fuller spin on this. There are actually no further commands. But, the file that ran the .sh script in the first place doesn't move on until it's completed the php tasks. Does that affect the situation?

Comment: Try this: `nohup php -f somescript.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &`